# clonezila reads bad sectors but I don't have any

Tags: windows-xp, bad-sectors, clonezilla

I am trying to clone my hard disk windows XP home edition , using clonezila live booting from USB.

I also checked the option * rescue , but still stops at 6.38% and after a short time clonezila crashes:

> "can't read bad sectors.. , lost data".

I have checked my HDD  with a lot of software and windows chkdsk and other programs and I don't have any bad sectors.

Is there any solution or other parameter that I can use?

Is it possible that antivirus or other program locks my HDD and doesn't let me clone?

Answer (score 0):

No, your antivirus or other programs aren't capable of doing anything if you boot from Clonezilla Live.

A complete chkdsk usually takes hours and it will only repair if you use the `/R` parameter. Did you do that? All those disk checkers are only worth it, if they are bootable or if you start them from a live CD. Out of windows they will never check the whole HDD and your bad sector might be somewhere where they cannot check.

It looks like your HDD simply is damaged (for real).

To force it to work you may use `-icrc` (ignore crc checking) parameter in Clonezilla, but I am not sure if that is a helpful option if he can't read the sector at all.

After crash you can only cancel and not continue?

This might also be helpful:
https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Help/thread/f8bc9fda/